# Make alert by the sql state by CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I make this sql in cloudwatch and make alarm by manually in aws console

```
 SELECT AVG(disk_used_percent) FROM "aka-dev" WHERE AutoScalingGroupName = 'aka-dev-ai-asg'
```

Now I want to make this in cdk script.

```
const gpuAlarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'aiGpuAlarm', {
  alarmName:metaInfo['alarmNameGpu'],
  comparisonOperator: cloudwatch.ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_THRESHOLD,
  threshold: 30,
  evaluationPeriods: 1,
  metric:new cloudwatch.Metric({
    namespace: `aka-dev`,
    metricName: `disk_used_percent`?
    static: 'ave',
    // I guess I need to do something here?

  })
});
```

I think I should put this sql in somewhere near `Metric` however I can't find the sample.

Is it possible to use `sql` in CDK or I should find some any other work-around?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [MathExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.MathExpression.html).

Something like:

```
const gpuAlarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'aiGpuAlarm', {
  alarmName:metaInfo['alarmNameGpu'],
  comparisonOperator: cloudwatch.ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_THRESHOLD,
  threshold: 30,
  evaluationPeriods: 1,
  metric: new MathExpression({
    expression: "SELECT AVG(disk_used_percent) FROM \"aka-dev\" WHERE AutoScalingGroupName = 'aka-dev-ai-asg'",
    usingMetrics: {},
    label: "disk_used_percent"
  })
});
```